# Smart Capture to create SF record

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, marketing-cloud-connect, cloudpage

My goal is to try to send data from Smart Form to Salesforce. So it would create a new record per submit and post the results of that form to it.

Through URL personalization it should be able to link it with an Account record as well.

Since getting the field data is simple enough through AMPscript [SFMC : Pre-populating Smart Capture Fields with Salesforce Data](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/smart_capture/smart_capture_advanced_procedures/salesforce_pre_populating_smart_capture_fields_with_salesforce_data/) I was wondering, how would I go about *creating* a new custom object record based on the Smart Capture form? Can I do this via AMPscript alone or do I need SSJS as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only do this with AMPScript and not SSJS. On your processing page you would need to use the [CreateSalesforceObject](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/ampscript_functions_for_use_with_salesforcecom/createsalesforceobject/) function. The function supports both standard and custom objects.

"Smart Capture"?... This would be code based landing page(s), rather than WYSIWYG designer with Smart Capture.